# How to change default Laravel Auth login view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to change the default login view, from Laravel Auth. Earlier suggestions points at modifying the path inside of the corresponding controller, under /vendor. However, this is a cooperative project, so modifying the vendor files is not an option.

By default the view for Auth login is `auth.login`, but i want it to be `backend.pages.login`.

In which other way can i accomplish this?

I have also tried to manually add the view routes in the router, but it won't recognize `Auth` as a class, no matter how i wire it up.

Note: It's Laravel 5.3

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController` define a fuction named `showLoginForm()` as:

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('custom.login');
}
```

It overrides the function `showLoginForm` defined in the trait `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers`.

***Note**: In Laravel 5.3 the function name is changed from `getLogin` to  `showLoginForm`.*

Comment: An additional related question: How'd i do this, with the registration page? 
Nevermind: I figured it out through the `RegistersUsers` file :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the question was already answered I'll give the same example for the current version of Laravel.

If you're on Laravel 5.6 and up, this functionality should be put in

> app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('custom.login');
}
```

Also, if you would like to add a parameter to this, you can do so if you specify it in your web route like this:

```
Route::get('login/{page?}', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
public function showLoginForm($page = null)
{
    if(isset($page)){
        // do something
        // example: return view('auth.login', compact('page'));
    }
    return view('auth.login');
}
```

Tip: if you don't have the LoginController in your project make sure you run

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Answer (score 0):

in your AuthenticatesUsers trait override this method :

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('login');
}
```

Comment: I've already seen this, but where is "AuthController" located?

Comment: Goto Your Project 
vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers file :)    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

Comment: You should never edit vendor files, you should override it on the controller that's using the Trait.

Answer (score 0):

trait AuthenticatesUsers
{
use RedirectsUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

```
/**
 * Show the application's login form.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('front.login');  //you can change every path you want
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).